# What would have happened if Dream had killed another Endless?

Tags: the-sandman

In The Sandman finale, we learn that

> Rose Walker is actually a descendent of Desire, and so is part of the Endless family. Desire's plan was to get Dream to inadvertently kill a member of the family.

Clearly a Rule would have been broken if Dream had killed this person, but what would the consequences have been?

Comment: He does precisely this in the source comic. In an act of fatherly pity, he kills his son [Orpheus](https://sandman.fandom.com/wiki/Orpheus) and is punished for this by the Furies, a set of immortal beings with the power to punish those that have committed blood sins

Comment: *Sandman* issue 49, "Brief Lives," number 9, FWIW.  Though it would be an interesting question to what extent Orpheus was actually still "alive" at that point...  (It might also be an interesting question, in the comics version, to what extent Desire was responsible for instigating the situation where Dream comes to kill his son.)

Comment: Be careful with wording. Rose wasn't one of the Endless, or even "part Endless". Only thing of importance was that she was a member of their family.

Comment: Spoilers - and potentially future works if the series ever actually gets renewed.

Comment: Back when the comics came out, I opined (on the compuserve Comics forum, yet) That regardless of the actual repercussions, Desire's ultimate goal for this plot was just for Dream to end up with egg on his face. A practical joke that took three generations to spring. Neil responded that I was "Spot on"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are Rules because beings even the Endless must respect set them.**

If the encounter with Lucifer Morningstar didn't make that clear, theres the earlier encounter with the Fates.  A still weak Morpheus treats the Three ladies of Fate with a great deal of respect.

> Another aspect of the Three is the Kindly Ones, or the Furies.  They are empowered to revenge those murdered by their own blood, which Rose would have qualified as.  There are other complications as they are depicted in the comics - someone mortal has to invoke and channel them, and it's an open question whether or not they actually can kill an Endless - but they are a divine and elemental force that make mere gods tremble.